# How do I find account id from a DocuSign account?

Tags: docusignapi, rest

This is my scenario: I have clients who have their accounts with DocuSign. They want to record the documents information onto our app. Our app would have to call DocuSign to "import" envelope data into our app. We will need `account_id` to call the Rest API `/envelopes`, etc...

How do our clients find their `account_id` to give to our app?

[image: Per Inbar's answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client need to go to the [apps and keys page](http://API%20Account%20ID) and find where it says **API Account ID** and copy the value (There's even a little icon to copy it to your clipboard).

Note that only administrators can access the above page, so your client admin must do this.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the description with the screenshot of the page. So, does that mean each of our clients will need to create a Developer Account in order to authenticate integration with DocuSign and with my app?

Comment: NO, you can use a single IK for multiple customers/accounts and they won't need to do anything like that.